# Boost.Log - how to configure text_file_backend with append and rotate

Tags: c++, logging, boost

How to create a text_file_backend that appends to existing file but also has rotation?
I do this, but a new file is created every time I run my program.

1. `App.log`
2. `App.log00000`
3. `App.log00001`
4. and so on and so forth ....

   ```
   boost::log::add_file_log
   (
       boost::log::keywords::auto_flush          = true,
       boost::log::keywords::target              = "Log",        
       boost::log::keywords::file_name           = "App.log",                                                  // file name pattern  eg: keywords::file_name = "app%m%d%Y_%H%M%S_%5N.log",    
       boost::log::keywords::open_mode           = std::ios::out | std::ios::app,                              // append mode 
       boost::log::keywords::rotation_size       = 10 * 1024 * 1024,                                           // rotate files every 10 MBytes
       boost::log::keywords::time_based_rotation = boost::log::sinks::file::rotation_at_time_point(0, 0, 0),   // ...or at midnight
   .....
   ```

Is there something else I can try?

Thanks

Comment: Please make the sample self-contained. Experience tells me this is going to rotate on startup. However, it's too much tedious to check whether your particular sample does indeed exhibit surprising behaviour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the `target` parameter you configured the target directory to be different from the directory where the log file is initially written (the `file_name` parameter), which means on rotation the file will be moved. Since the file name contains no placeholders that could differentiate the files, the new file clashes with the ones left in the target directory from previous rotations, and a counter suffix is appended to avoid the conflict.

Appending only works when the sink backend opens the file identified by `file_name` and it already exists. It does not make the file appended to an existing file in the target directory on rotation, this is not possible. Since in your case the rotation moves the file away every time, appending will never happen.

In order for appending and rotation both to work you have to ensure that (a) the previous file written by the sink backend is left in the same directory and has the same name as the new sink tries to open and (b) the file name contains some placeholders so that on every rotation a new file name is generated. These are conflicting requirements but some configurations can meet them. For example, you can configure the target directory to be the same as where the log file is written by the backend, the file name to contain a date and rotate each day on midnight.

```
boost::log::add_file_log
(
    boost::log::keywords::auto_flush          = true,
    boost::log::keywords::target              = "Log",        
    boost::log::keywords::file_name           = "Log/App_%Y%m%d.log",
    boost::log::keywords::open_mode           = std::ios::out | std::ios::app,
    boost::log::keywords::time_based_rotation = boost::log::sinks::file::rotation_at_time_point(0, 0, 0)
);
```

Note that file counters and rotation on file size do not work well with appending because they tend to violate one of the requirements I listed.

Comment: I see that appending to last rotated log file is not supported in boost (https://sourceforge.net/p/boost-log/discussion/710022/thread/a5b15460/). Since this discussion was old, just wanted to check, is this supported now? If so how to achieve it?

Comment: It is supported but only if the newly opened file name is exactly the same as the last one written to. You need to pass `std::ios_base::app` to `text_file_backend::set_open_mode` (https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/log/doc/html/boost/log/sinks/text_file_backend.html#idp47562000-bb).

Comment: I'm using size based rotation by using %N% modifier for file names. I'm using `logging::add_file_log` to open file sink. I've set `target` (same folder as log files), `file_name` (name_%N%.log), `rotation_size` (10MB), `auto_flush` (true) & `open_mode` (`std::ios_base::app`). With this setting how can I open the last modified file ? Do I need to use time based rotation for it to work?

Comment: If you don't scan for earlier files on startup then the file counter will be 0, so if there is a file that matches the pattern with counter 0, that file will be appended to. Which is likely not what you want, certainly not if there are files with greater counter values from the previous runs of your app. If you scan for files, the initial counter value will be next after the last counter in the found files, so appending won't happen. Which means counters are not well suited for appending. Date/time in the file name pattern instead of counter may help in this case.

Comment: If I don't use counter for file name, file rotation will not happen. It ignores the `rotation_size` and keeps writing to same log file. My first requirement is `file rotation` should work. Second, it should `append` to last log file when restarting the process. Looks like I cannot meet second requirement with this configuration. I'll go with new log file when process restarts for now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `keywords::enable_final_rotation` to **false** (example [here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/log/doc/html/log/detailed/sink_backends.html#log.detailed.sink_backends.text_file)) in order to not rotate when your process exits.
This way, the next time your process start up, if the file was not rotated because of size / time rules, it will append to it.

Also, I would suggest to set `keywords::target_file_name` with a pattern (e.g. `"App_%Y%m%d_%H%M%S_%5N.log"`) so that the rotated files have distinct names (containing the date and an index in this case).
If you don't do this, you will have max 1 rotated file (Log/App.log) which will be overwritten by the next rotated file.